# R help - either/or function?

Tags: r, dimensions

Very new coder over here so excuse me if this is overwhelmingly simple.

I'm trying to build a dataframe to sort certain data points (x) that fall beyond given dimensions but I'm having trouble doing so.

```
 outside <- subset(dataframe, x == "1" & wid < 1 | wid > 5 | hei < 1 | hei > 5)
```

x is a binary variable, so I'm just looking for 1s.

After corrections, this current formula seems just to determine any points in the dataset that fall outside of the dimensions but is counting x variables of both 0 and 1.

Thanks for your help everybody! Sorry I'm new to this website (and code, for that matter).

Comment: Sorry that second "wid" should be a "hei"

Comment: the pipe `|` is the symbol for "OR"

Comment: Edit your question. Do not add corrections in the comments.

Comment: Operators in R also have help pages: `help("&")` will also tell you about OR `|` as well as other logical operators.

Comment: It did not fully work apparently. I'm trying to create a dataframe to sort out certain data points (x) that fall outside of given dimensions. The current code I have going is:

> outside <- subset(dataset, x == "1" & wid > 1 | wid < 5 | hei > 1 | hei < 5)

Essentially I'm trying to group together every time that data point x is outside of this 1x5 box. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Edit your question with the extra information. Also include an example data set that we can use to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If your condition works apart from the `x == "1"` part, then you probably just need to use parens to group the conditions:

```
outside <- subset(dataframe, (x == "1") & (wid < 1 | wid > 5 | hei < 1 | hei > 5))
```

As conditions get more complex it sometimes helps to separate these out, e.g.:

```
x_match = x == "1"
outside_box = wid < 1 | wid > 5 | hei < 1 | hei > 5
outside = subset(dataframe, x_match & outside_box)
```